# Trying to add GEOJSON as marker on mapbox

Tags: javascript, api, jsx, mapbox, geojson

I would like my map to display GEOJSON as markers which it currently does.

I created 3 files to make 3 different API calls.
However, only the first script file is executed and the rest are ignored.

I would like the markers to be displayed based on the users chosen file path . (e.g `"/daily"`, `"/"`, `"monthly"`)

At the moment the `mapbox` `markers` are  is only using the data from the first script. The data only changes when I manually swap the script files around.

This is my first StackOverFlow question, so I am unable to post picture of my results. I have linked my issue with pictures of the the marker rendering out data based on the order of script files.

My Pr: https://github.com/Rhianna20/disaster_check/pull/13

My issue: https://github.com/Rhianna20/disaster_check/issues/14

I would appreciate any tips or advice on this, thank you!

**My code**
[dailyMapbox.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWInq.png)

The `client/monthly`, `client/daily` files all contain the same code apart from the `url` value being different.

I then placed the script files  inside of [document.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKuYT.png)

Here is my [app.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ucXc.png) file structure. Which does not use my `client/public` files. Instead `document.js` is called on each file path.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In your Issue we can see this error : `Identifier map has been declared`.

The problem is that you add 3 scripts to your HTML, and the same variable `map` is declared in the 3 scripts.

- Do you have control on the files client/daily and client/monthly ?
  If yes and if you know a little javascript, you can implement the user-chosen
  map yourself.
- If not, you can create a `select` element where users can choose an existing
  file and then choose to only display this file...

In either way you will need to get your hands dirty in javascript.

We can help you more, but we will need you to add some relevant code in your question

Comment: I've added some code to my post - I do not have controls on the `client/daily` files. I could give the `select` element a try, appreciate any help, thank you.